# Wait until timer stops for continuing

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, timer

I have a program in Visual Basic 2010 which emulates a slot machine.

Firstly I generate 3 random numbers from 1 to 9, and as I wanted to simulate the "spins" I decided to go through a loop in which images of the slot machine fruits and things appear in screen. After this loop ends, user should get the corresponding pictures for that 1 to 9 numbers generated.

So I saw the best idea was to set up a timer, put an interval of 100 for example and start it, and in each tick show some random images in the screen.

However, it seems that when I start my timer, it goes like parallel to the main function from which it's called. I don't know if I'm being informative here XD.
Better look for yourselves:

```
'CALCULATE WINNING RESULT
valor1 = GeneraAleatorio(1, 9)   -> This custom function returns a random number
valor2 = GeneraAleatorio(1, 9)
valor3 = GeneraAleatorio(1, 9)

Timer1.Enabled = True

'NOW I PUT THE WINNING PICTURES THAT CORRESPOND WITH THE NUMBERS
ColocaImagen(1, valor1)  -> Another custom made function, takes the position (1 to 3) and an image (1 to 9)
ColocaImagen(2, valor2)
ColocaImagen(3, valor3)

'END GAME
End()          -> or whatever
```

My timer_tick function is this:

```
    If tiempo >= 4000 Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False        ' -> To make it stop when it reaches 4000 (4 seconds)

    ElseIf tiempo <= 3900 Then

        ColocaImagen(1, GeneraAleatorio(1, 9))
        ColocaImagen(2, GeneraAleatorio(1, 9))
        ColocaImagen(3, GeneraAleatorio(1, 9))

        If tiempo >= ProgressBar.Minimum & tiempo <= ProgressBar.Maximum Then
            ProgressBar.Value = tiempo         
        End If

        tiempo = tiempo + 100                  'Tiempo is "time" in Spanish, it increases 100 every 100ms
    End If
```

It seems that when I call timer1.enabled = true, it continues both ways: The program enters the tick functions, but also goes towards the end of the game without waiting for the timer to stop. I want 4 seconds to pass, THEN showing the correct pictures, and the executing whatever action I want , or showing a msgbox or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a SubRoutine and call it when your Timer reaches 4000. See if something like this will work for you.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim valor1 As Integer
    Dim valor2 As Integer
    Dim valor3 As Integer


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Timer1.Enabled Then Exit Sub
        'CALCULATE WINNING RESULT
        valor1 = GeneraAleatorio(1, 9)
        valor2 = GeneraAleatorio(1, 9)
        valor3 = GeneraAleatorio(1, 9)
        Timer1.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    Public Sub ShowFinalResult()
        'NOW I PUT THE WINNING PICTURES THAT CORRESPOND WITH THE NUMBERS
        ColocaImagen(1, valor1)
        ColocaImagen(2, valor2)
        ColocaImagen(3, valor3)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Static tiempo As Integer
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        If tiempo >= 4000 Then
             tiempo = 0
             ShowFinalResult()

        ElseIf tiempo <= 3900 Then

            ColocaImagen(1, GeneraAleatorio(1, 9))
            ColocaImagen(2, GeneraAleatorio(1, 9))
            ColocaImagen(3, GeneraAleatorio(1, 9))

            tiempo = tiempo + 100 

            If tiempo >= ProgressBar1.Minimum And tiempo <= ProgressBar1.Maximum Then ProgressBar1.Value = tiempo

            Timer1.Enabled = True
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks! I decided to follow your advice and created a sub, which depending on whether the player has won or not (Maybe later I will change it to a point-scheme) does some actions or calls another sub.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

While (Timer1.Enabled) {} // Will keep blocking until the timer ends

```
'CALCULATE WINNING RESULT
valor1 = GeneraAleatorio(1, 9)   -> This custom function returns a random number
valor2 = GeneraAleatorio(1, 9)
valor3 = GeneraAleatorio(1, 9)

Timer1.Enabled = True

While (Timer1.Enabled) {} // Will keep blocking until the timer sets Enabled to false

'NOW I PUT THE WINNING PICTURES THAT CORRESPOND WITH THE NUMBERS
ColocaImagen(1, valor1)  -> Another custom made function, takes the position (1 to 3) and an image (1 to 9)
ColocaImagen(2, valor2)
ColocaImagen(3, valor3)

'END GAME
End()          -> or whatever
```

Starting the timer doesn't cause the program to stop and wait.

Also:

> The while loop would eat up the CPU without a Sleep inside of it – pinkfloydx33

Comment: The while loop would eat up the CPU without a Sleep inside of it

Comment: Good point, I'm going to make a note of that in my answer.  Props!

Comment: Yeah, that would have been great except for that CPU usage :( I decided to end my function when starting the timer and continue in another one when stopping it